# I was born with/into something

Tags: prepositions

Are these correct?

1. I was born **with** the wrong gender.
2. I was born **into** the wrong gender.
3. I was born the wrong gender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 1 is grammatically correct. One is born **with** certain physical attributes, whether a hair lip, a deformed foot or large ears.

Whether you are born **with** a gender takes you into a different semantic field. Many people argue that while you are born with certain (male/female) sexual characteristics, you later grow into or adopt a gender. They would challenge the notion that you are born with a gender or with the wrong gender.

It is not grammatically correct to say that you were born **into** a gender or **born a gender**.

https://www.who.int/genomics/gender/en/index1.html
https://amaze.org/video/gender-identity-sex-at-birth/

Comment: I don't see anything _grammatically_ wrong with saying "born into a gender". Depending on your understanding of the word, you may regard it as factually impossible, but the grammar is fine.

Comment: @ColinFine True, the audience might query the speaker's intended meaning but the grammar is impeccable.